# Override toString() method of final BluetoothDevice class

Tags: java, android, overriding, android-arrayadapter, tostring

In my Android app I have a `ListActivity` which displays bluetooth devices. I have an `ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>` and `ArrayAdapter<BluetoothDevice>`. Everything works but there is one problem. Each `BluetoothDevice` is displayed as a MAC address in the list but I need to display its name.

As I know adapter calls `toString` method on each object. But `BluetoothDevice` returns MAC address if you call `toString` on it. So solution would be to override `toString` and return name instead of address. But `BluetoothDevice` is final class so I am not able to override it!

Any ideas how to force Bluetooth device to return its name instead address? `toString`?

Comment: Extend ArrayAdapter and use other Method inside the adapter instead of toString

Comment: thx for the response - i added my comment as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i already mentioned in the comment you could extend the ArrayAdapter and 
use another method instead of the toString Method.

For Example like so:

```
public class YourAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<BluetoothDevice> {
   ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> devices;
   //other stuff
 @Override
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
   //get view and the textView to show the name of the device
   textView.setText(devices.get(position).getName());
   return view;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

you could use composition instead of inheritance:

```
 public static class MyBluetoothDevice {
     BluetoothDevice mDevice;
     public MyBluetoothDevice(BluetoothDevice device) {
        mDevice = device;
     }

     public String toString() {
          if (mDevice != null) {
             return mDevice.getName();
          } 
          // fallback name
          return "";
     } 
 }
```

and off course your `ArrayAdapter`, will use `MyBluetoothDevice` instead of `BluetoothDevice`

Comment: Yes, this could be the solution. But I am using many methods and fields from BluetoothDevice so I would implement all these methods within MyBluetoothDevice class...

Comment: you could have a getter that returns the `BluetoothDevice` object

Answer (score 2):

Once you have your ArrayList

```
ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> btDeviceArray = new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();
ArrayAdapter<String> mArrayAdapter;
```

Now you can add the devices in the **onCreateView** for example:

```
mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
mArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1);
        setListAdapter(mArrayAdapter);

Set<BluetoothDevice> pariedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
        if(pariedDevices.size() > 0){
            for(BluetoothDevice device : pariedDevices){
                mArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
                btDeviceArray.add(device);
            }
        }
```

So note that you can get the name with the `.getName()` method. This solve your problem?

Comment: But ArrayList and ArrayAdapter must contain objects of the same type. In your proposal ArrayList contains BluetoothDevice objects and ArrayAdapter contains String objects. This throws error...